# how to synchornize a custom list with the excel file stored in a local machine?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

i have a custom list created in sharepoint 2007.
is it possible to have an excel file in the local machine so that when i update the excel file in the local machine and save. the updations happens in the sharepoint custom list.
i have office 2010 installed in my machine.
please help in what ways i can achieve the same ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a method which involves some workflow process too.

Please read the post - http://rstagg.wordpress.com/2010/04/13/how-to-bulk-upload-and-synchronize-data-into-sharepoint-using-the-excel-add-in-and-sharepoint-designer-workflows/

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: blocked at my organization :(